# Display flex not getting 100% height in firefox

Tags: css

I am trying to display a div instead of element in fullcalendar using html and css via jquery as follows:

```
$(element).css("display", "none");
                        $('.fc-day[data-date="' + event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + '"]').append("<div class='booked'><span>Booked <br><small>for date</small></span></div>");
```

And css

```
.booked{
  display: -webkit-box;      
  display: -moz-box;       
  display: -ms-flexbox;   
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #CD5C5C;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Although, its working fine as intended on chrome but not on other browsers such as firefox.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Firefox

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

### Update:

If I inspect each container:

In chrome

```
<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2019-06-23">
    <div class="booked"><span>Booked <br><small>for date</small></span></div>
</td>
```

But in case of firefox, its not showing inner element i.e `div .booked`
[image: Firfox inspect]

**CODEPEN LINK**

You can check this link its showing my problem, you can check in chrome and firefox.

[CODEPEN LINK](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQEgYR)

Comment: please share full Code for better understanding.

Comment: You may need to give the parent container a `position` of `relative`

Comment: instead of height =100% try setting min-height, with a fixed say 50px;

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Please take a look I have updated it. If you need any more information please let me know

Comment: @Nimsrules Its not working with the suggested answers of min height

Comment: @akshaykishore its not working

Comment: try align-items: stretch?

Comment: trying on jsfiddle at my firefox, it's working [proof](https://imgur.com/OOMFtks)

Comment: @dooooooofai it could have better if you had shared the link for jsfiddle. So that, it might be helpful for me.

Comment: what i do only copy paste you're code .. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcns0myg/)

Comment: Now you can reference the codepen link, I have updated it in questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mising is, you forget making the td height 100% too. So you need add css for the td. In my opinion, try to add this css

```
.fc-bg td {
height: 100%;
 }
```

and it will work.

Already trying on the pen, and it's working. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqxBYQ)